# Entity Framework Code First Migration for Computed Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to add a computed column **HasAnyCheck** that returns true if any or both **Check1** and **Check2** is true.

My model:

```
public bool Check1 { get; set; }

public bool Check2 { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public bool HasAnyCheck { get; private set; }
```

My migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [HasAnyCheck] AS ([Check1] = 1 OR [Check2] = 1)");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.MyTable", "HasAnyCheck");
    }
```

When I run **Update-Database** I get the error **Incorrect syntax near '='**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is your [computed_column_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does not explicitly return a value:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [HasAnyCheck] AS CAST((CASE WHEN [Check1]=1 OR [Check2]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT)
```

in your case you could potentially also get away with [bitwise OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD [HasAnyCheck] AS ([Check1]|[Check2])
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work as expected as the computed column created ended up as int instead of boolean/bit field. However, the second solution did work as expected.

Comment: i updated the first solution to explicitly cast the result to `BIT` - should probably be better now